# Scanamo Paginated Query Issues

Tags: scala, pagination, amazon-dynamodb, implicit, scanamo

Need example of a method to create paginated query on dynamoDb using scala's, Scanamo library

I am trying to create to create a method which performs paginated queries on dynamodb table using a query on secondary index.
I tried using scanamo but this doesn't works.... Additionally I am not sure how **queryPaginatedM()** works, since there is not much documentation available for scala newbies.

https://github.com/scanamo/scanamo/blob/master/scanamo/src/main/scala/org/scanamo/SecondaryIndex.scala

```
    protected def querySecondaryIndexPaginated[T, U](
          query: Query[T],
          table: Table[U],
          indexName: String,
          pageSize: Int,
          lastEvaluatedKeyOpt: Option[Map[String, AttributeValue]]
      )(implicit format: DynamoFormat[T]): Future[MyDynamoResult[U]] = {
        val queryRequest: ScanamoOps[List[Either[DynamoReadError, U]]] = lastEvaluatedKeyOpt match {
          case Some(lastEvaluatedKey) => table.index(indexName).limit(pageSize).from(UniqueKey(lastEvaluatedKey)).query(query = query)
          case None                   => table.index(indexName).limit(pageSize).query(query = query)
        }
        scanamo
          .execFuture(queryRequest)
          .map....
```

Comment: What code did you try? What error did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: I am trying to use the scanamo library functions, i.e queryPaginatedM() and from() to build a paginated method, but it keeps on giving errors in IDE. I am new to scala and scanamo lacks documentation.

Comment: What errors? Please post the code you use and the errors you get. Otherwise we cannot help!

Comment: The issue is this scanamo library is not very clear, with 0 documentation. I am looking for usage of from() method so that I can create paginated Queries. But it is not clear how to extract lastEvaluatedKey from the response.
Similar issue with queryPaginatedM(), no documentation or examples on how to use this.


from() - https://github.com/scanamo/scanamo/blob/77c57a7f81c224b44ca8458b390c07c8bfa2eac8/scanamo/src/main/scala/org/scanamo/SecondaryIndex.scala#L95